# Is default methods are supported in AIDL (Android) for Java 8?

Tags: android, kotlin, java-8, aidl

I have previous implementation of AIDL for IPC in android. I want to add new method as this aidl has multiple implementation in client class and I don't want to implement for all classes.. I want to use default method just like its supported in Java 8.

Answer (score 1):

The `default` keyword should be available in any `interface` description, even if generated from `AIDL`. This will not be backwards compatible with Java 7, so it might require `minSdkVersion 26` and:

```
android {
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, implemented the same. but when I write any default method in AIDL interface file compiler simply don't accept it.

Comment: Either your building with Java 7 or the `default` keyword might still be unknown to the AIDL processor. When manually defining the `interface` instead of generating it, it should still work. Probably that's worth a bug report.

Answer (score 0):

Use it who is stopping you?

Inside interface you can write your code like below:

```
default void show() { 

  System.out.println("Default method here"); 
}
```